# Sum without Highest and lower number js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to complete a kata inside codewars, but I'm having some problems. I would like to sum all elements inside an array except the **highest** and **lower** values.

This is what I have now

```
function sumArray(array) {

  let largestVal =  Math.max(array);
  let lowestVal =  Math.min(array);
  let total =  0;

  let arrLength = array.length;

  console.log(`The lowest number is: ${lowestVal}`);
  console.log(`Array is: ${array}`);
  console.log(`Total is: ${total}`);
  console.log(`The larget number is: ${largestVal}`);
  return  // [QUESTION] <= having problems in how to return the sum of each element except the largest and lowest values.  
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT-1:** Updated code with @WLatif implementation

```
function validate(array) {
  if (typeof array === 'object' && array instanceof Array && array.length > 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

function sumArray(array) {
  if (validate(array)) {
    let sorted = array.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
    let largestVal = sorted.slice(-1).pop();
    let lowestVal =  sorted[0];
    let total =  array.reduce( function(prev, curr) { return prev + curr; }, 0 );
    let arrLength = array.length;

    console.log(`The lowest number is: ${lowestVal}`);
    console.log(`Array is: ${array}`);
    console.log(`Total is: ${total}`);
    console.log(`The larget number is: ${largestVal}`);
    return (total- lowestVal - largestVal);
  } else {
    console.log(`Not a valid array`);
  }

}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Not a valid array ✘ Expected: 0, instead got: undefined

What am I missing?

Here are the instructions:

```
Sum all the numbers of the array except the highest and the lowest element (the value, not the index!).
(Only one element at each edge, even if there are more than one with the same value!)

Example:

{ 6, 2, 1, 8, 10 } => 16
{ 1, 1, 11, 2, 3 } => 6


If array is empty, null or None, or if only 1 Element exists, return 0.
```

Comment: total--largestval-lowestVal

Comment: sum all values then subtract maximum and minimum value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by sorting(Ascending order) the array first and then doing the operations neglecting first(smallest) and last(largest) element.
Attached is the snippet
Best of luck.
**Edit 1**: added validation cases.

```js
function validate(array) {
  if (typeof array === 'object' && array instanceof Array && array.length > 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

function sumArray(array) {
  var sorted = array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
  console.log(`The lowest number is: ${sorted[0]}`);
  console.log(`Array is: ${array}`);
  console.log(`Total is: ${sorted.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0)}`);
  console.log(`The larget number is: ${sorted.slice(-1).pop()}`);
  return sorted.slice(1, -1).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
}

// ideal case
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
if (validate(points)) {
  console.log(`sum of numbers except smallest and largest number is: ${sumArray(points)}`);
} else {
  console.log("Array validation unsuccessful");
}

//empty array case
var points = [];
if (validate(points)) {
  console.log(`sum of numbers except smallest and largest number is: ${sumArray(points)}`);
} else {
  console.log("Array validation unsuccessful");
}

// single element case
var points = [40];
if (validate(points)) {
  console.log(`sum of numbers except smallest and largest number is: ${sumArray(points)}`);
} else {
  console.log("Array validation unsuccessful");
}

//other data type case
var points = "x";
if (validate(points)) {
  console.log(`sum of numbers except smallest and largest number is: ${sumArray(points)}`);
} else {
  console.log("Array validation unsuccessful");
}

//null case
var points = null;
if (validate(points)) {
  console.log(`sum of numbers except smallest and largest number is: ${sumArray(points)}`);
} else {
  console.log("Array validation unsuccessful");
}
```

Comment: `let` was not supported by the `stacksnippets` so I used `var`.

Comment: It passes the first test, but then I get the following error when I run the full test suite `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of null`

Comment: Can you share the suite inputs. `sort` is an array method, and it will throw this error is any other data type is used to call it. We can add a check in the method if it is an array, then proceed, else return false.

Comment: I need to verify `If array is empty, null or None, or if only 1 Element exists, return 0.`

Comment: check it out; I have added the validation also.

Comment: Hey updated the code with your above validation. But I'm still not getting the test to pass. I'm going  crazy here, thanks for all your help though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125911/discussion-between-wlatif-and-d-s).

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumArray(array) {
    if (array == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (array.length < 2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        array = array.sort(function(a,b) {return a - b;});
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            total += array[i];
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd be nice to add some explanation complementing your code. This question already have an accepted answer, so, if you think your answer is better consider adding some reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution can be more concise.
First, we determine the edge cases, then we sort the array and calculate the sum of the remaining values.

```
function sumArray(array) {
      // edge cases
        if(array == null) return 0 
        if(array.length < 3) return 0
    
        let sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => a - b) 
        let sum = 0 
      
        for(let i = 1; i < sortedArray.length - 1; i++){
          sum = sum + sortedArray[i];
        }
        return sum
    }
```

or

```
function sumArray(array)  {
    if(array && array.length > 1) {
        const sortedArray = array.sort((a,b) => a - b).slice(1, -1)
        return sortedArray.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0)
    }

    return 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want something like that:

```
function sumArray(array) {
    let largestVal =  Math.max.apply(Math, array);
    let lowestVal =  Math.min.apply(Math, array);
    let total = array.reduce(function(v1, v2){return v1+v2}, 0);

    let arrLength = array.length;

    console.log(`The lowest number is: ${lowestVal}`);
    console.log(`Array is: ${array}`);
    console.log(`Total is: ${total}`);
    console.log(`The larget number is: ${largestVal}`);

    return total - largestVal - lowestVal;
}
```